# Hi I am working on Cucumber and i am trying to generate pdf report, in my porm i have added dependency but still showing error missing ralfstuckert

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

**POM.xml**
As You can see in following code i have added ralfstuckert Dependency in My POM but still showing "Missing artifact com.github.ralfstuckert.pdfbox-layout:pdfbox2-layout:jar:1.0.0" What should i do for solve this issue.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Cucumbar_BDD</groupId>
    <artifactId>CucumberJavaHybridFramwork</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>CucumberJavaHybridFramwork</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <junit.version>4.13.1</junit.version>
        <cucumber.version>6.9.0</cucumber.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
        <maven.surefire.version>2.22.2</maven.surefire.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber6-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ralfstuckert.pdfbox-layout</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox2-layout</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/ParallelRun.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <threadCount>4</threadCount>
                    <useUnlimitedThreads>false</useUnlimitedThreads>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId> 
                    <version>3.0.0-M3</version> <executions> <execution> <goals> <goal>integration-test</goal> 
                    </goals> <configuration> UNCOMMENT - To add any exclusions if required <excludes> 
                    <exclude>**/*IT*.java</exclude> </excludes> <includes> UNCOMMENT BELOW LINE 
                    - To execute feature files with a single runner <include>**/MyTestRunner.java</include> 
                    UNCOMMENT BELOW LINE - To execute feature files with multiple runners <include>**/*Runner.java</include> 
                    </includes> UNCOMMENT BELOW 3 LINES - To execute using parallel or combination 
                    option <parallel>methods</parallel> <threadCount>4</threadCount> <perCoreThreadCount>true</perCoreThreadCount> 
                    UNCOMMENT BELOW 3 LINES - To execute using forking or combination option 
                    <forkCount>2</forkCount> <reuseForks>true</reuseForks> <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/failsafe-reports_${surefire.forkNumber}</reportsDirectory> 
                    </configuration> </execution> </executions> </plugin> -->


        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**ERROR**

Missing artifact com.github.ralfstuckert.pdfbox-layout:pdfbox2-layout:jar:1.0.0

Comment: https://github.com/grasshopper7/extentreports-cucumber6-adapter/issues/36

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I used below dependency:

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber5-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

"extentreports-cucumber5-adapter" with version 2.8.1 instead of "extentreports-cucumber6-adapter"

This resolved my issue. You can refer below github link:
https://github.com/grasshopper7/cuke5-extent-adapter-report/blob/master/cuke5-extent-adapter-report/pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the version of adapter as below. This worked for me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber6-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```